# Set of rule with alternative - How to avoid reportAttemptingFullContext and reportContextSensitivity

Tags: antlr4

I am having some trouble understanding 'reportAttemptingFullContext' and 'reportContextSensitivity' and some trouble avoiding theses in my grammars. Here an example:

```
IF L_COUNT > 0 THEN
    LINEFEED;
END IF;
```

Here an excerpt of my grammar:

```
if_statement
:   
IF plsql_condition THEN 
seq_of_statements? elsif_statement* else_statement? END IF
;

plsql_condition
    :   expr_bool
    ;

expr_bool
:
expr_or (OR expr_or)*
;

expr_or
:
expr_and (AND expr_and)*
;

expr_and
:
NOT? expr_not
;

expr_not
:
expr_not_is |
expr_not_between |
expr_not_in |
expr_not_op |
expr_add
;
```

And the error messages:

```
line 1:13 TIME: 2013-02-12 09:15:52.225, reportAttemptingFullContext d=116, rule='expr_not', input='L_COUNT > 0'
line 1:11 TIME: 2013-02-12 09:15:52.228,reportContextSensitivity d=116, rule='expr_not', input='L_COUNT >'
line 1:11 TIME: 2013-02-12 09:15:52.354, reportAttemptingFullContext d=120, rule='expr_not_op', input='>'
line 1:11 TIME: 2013-02-12 09:15:52.355,reportContextSensitivity d=120, rule='expr_not_op', input='>'
```

The grammar as a whole is quite big. This is a simple example. I have basically an issue every time I have alternatives (as in 'expr_not' above). How am I to avoid these? I have tried using semantic predicate but this is only possible (as far as I know) if the position of tokens in the rule are fixed at code generation time. When commenting in the following code (more complexe example):

```
COLUMN FORMAT FORMAT.PRICE(OBJ_CURRY(TOP.STRIKE_CURRY_ID).RD(TOP.INTR_PAY * (TOP.NOTE_RATIO * L_ALLOC)),TOP.STRIKE_CURRY_ID);
```

I multiply the parsing time by 20; this is rather painful. In this case also I get a 'reportAttemptingFullContext'.

My question:
How can I avoid the 'reportAttemptingFullContext' in alternatives.

Thank you for your help.
Kind regards, Wolfgang Hämmer

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with full context parsing is the potential performance impact (depending on how often it's needed and how much lookahead is required to resolve the SLL conflict). If your grammar is unambiguous in SLL mode, then the two-stage parsing strategy describe in the ANTLR book (with [one implementation here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/TestPerformance.java)) will prevent full-context parsing for all source files which do not contain syntax errors. Two-stage parsing always produces the same end result as parsing with full-context enabled, but gains a major performance advantage for grammars+inputs meeting the following properties.

1. The majority of source files being parsed do not contain syntax errors.
2. The majority of source files not containing syntax errors give the same parse tree for `PredictionMode.SLL` and `PredictionMode.LL` (see the [`PredictionMode`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/PredictionMode.java) enumeration).